# Blazor custom dropdown with HTML select and sorting by text, not value for enums

Tags: c#, select, enums, blazor, dropdown

I'm trying to build a custom Blazor dropdown component for enums that is able to sort the enum members by their **display value / text**. I have the following code:

```
<div>
    <select value="@this.SelectedValue" @onchange="@this.OnSelectedValueChanged" @key="@this.Items">
        @foreach (var value in this.Items)
        {
            // Use enum value as value and display name as text.
            if (value is Enum enumName)
            {
                <option id="@value" value="@value">@enumName.GetDisplayName(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

the sort order enum:

```cs
public enum SortOrder
{
    None,
    Ascending,
    Descending
}
```

and in the code behind file:

```cs
private List<TItem?> OriginalItems { get; set; } = [];

[Parameter]
[EditorRequired]
public IEnumerable<TItem?> Items { get; set; } = [];

[Parameter]
public TItem? SelectedValue { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<TItem?> SelectedValueChanged { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<TItem?> OnValueChanged { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    this.OriginalItems = this.Items.ToList();
    this.SortItems();
}

protected async Task OnSelectedValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Value is not string value)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (this.SelectedValue is Enum _)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = (TItem?)Enum.Parse(typeof(TItem?), value);
            await this.SelectedValueChanged.InvokeAsync(result);
            await this.OnValueChanged.InvokeAsync(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }
}

private void SortItems()
{
    if (this.SortOrder == SortOrder.None)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (typeof(TItem).BaseType == typeof(Enum))
    {
        this.Items = this.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ?
            [.. this.Items.OrderBy(f => (f as Enum)?.GetDisplayNameForEnum(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))] :
            [.. this.Items.OrderByDescending(f => (f as Enum)?.GetDisplayNameForEnum(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))];
    }
}
```

The `GetDisplayValue` function just gets a display value for the enums and is implemented for all enums that are put into the dropdown, e.g.:

```cs
private static string GetDisplayName(this SortOrder order, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var de = culture.Name.StartsWith("de");

    return order switch
    {
        SortOrder.None => de ? "Keine" : "None",
        SortOrder.Ascending => de ? "Aufsteigend" : "Ascending",
        SortOrder.Descending => de ? "Absteigend" : "Descending",
        _ => $"[[{type}]]"
    };
}
```

There is also an input field to filter, a filter method, filter size and several other things like ids that are set. However, I removed these as they're not relevant for the question. `TItem` is a generic member (And only used for Enums in my case).

When I add the component to a page, initial sorting works. Searching works. However, when I select one of the items, the sorting is ignored and the `select` seems to fall back / "Sort" by the enum member value (e.g. what is specified in `value=` of the `option`). Is there a way to always have the `select` sort by the display name even after the value selection has changed (After `OnSelectedValueChanged()` was called)?

**Hint**: Calling `SortItems()` at the end of `OnSelectedValueChanged()` doesn't work.
**Hint 2**: Calling `SortItems()` before `this.OriginalItems = this.Items.ToList();` in `OnInitialized()` doesn't help either.
**Hint 3**: Using the list index of `this.Items` as value in the select after sorting the list doesn't work either plus has the downgrade that the selected value is properly set, but not shown in the dropdown anymore.

Comment: I'm confused and probably totally missing the point.  If you want to create a select for an enum, then why are you passing in `public IEnumerable<TItem?> Items { get; set; } = []`?  Surely you just pass in the enum type and iterate `Enum.GetValues` in the control to get the possible values?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Theoretically yes, but I wanted to exclude some enum members in some cases and in some cases not. Therefore I can decide in the parent page whether all members should be used or not. A restriction like `TItem: Enum` would be useful, but doesn't work somehow with Blazor and nullables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with now was to rewrite the `SortItems` function to return a value whether the collection was changed (e.g. resorted) and then use `OnAfterRender()` to call `StateHasChanged()`.

Changes:

```cs
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (!firstRender)
    {
        if (this.SortItems())
        {
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
}

private bool SortItems()
{
    if (this.SortOrder == SortOrder.None)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeof(TItem).BaseType == typeof(Enum))
    {
        var initialItems = this.Items.ToList();
        this.Items = this.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ?
            [.. this.Items.OrderBy(f => (f as Enum)?.GetDisplayName(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))] :
            [.. this.Items.OrderByDescending(f => (f as Enum)?.GetDisplayName(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))];
        return !Enumerable.SequenceEqual(initialItems, this.Items);
    }

    return false;
}
```